# How to add the values of c?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // Write C code here
    int a, b = 1, c, d;
    printf("Value of a:");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    
    while (b < a) {
        c = b * a;
        printf("%d", c);
        b++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to find the factorial of a number but I don't know how to add the values.
It's written in C.

Comment: How would you solve it in plain math with pen & paper?

Comment: You're making the typical mistake of giving non-meaning names to your variables (a, b, c and why do you even create a "d" if you don't use it?). Start by giving your variables meaningful names, try to imagine how they should evolve through your program and you'll find out.

Comment: First of all, it isn't a very good practice to use uninitialized variables, as they might not be holding the value of zero (on some languages it is true, others it isn't so for the sake of consistency upholding that standard is more beneficial than not doing it at all). Second of all, try to define the problem in a mathematical way and then parse it to code.  Last but not least you can assing a variable and reference it in the same line, like ```c = c + b * a```.

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems in your code:

- the expression `c = b * a;` computes an intermediary result, but not a useful one. You should compute `c = c * b;` multiplying the current factorial by the next integer to get the next factorial.
- for the expression `c = c * b;` you must initialize `c` to `1` before the beginning of the loop.
- `printf("%d", c);` outputs just the digits. You should output a space or a newline to separate the numbers.
- `scanf("%d", &a)` may fail to convert a number from user input, for example if the user typed `A`. `a` will stay uninitialized, causing undefined behavior when you use it in further expressions. You should test that `scanf()` succeeded and returned `1`, the number of successful conversions.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a, b = 1, c = 1;

    printf("Value of a:");
    if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1) {
        while (b < a) {
            c = c * b;
            printf("%d\n", c);
            b++;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It is recommended to use the `for` loop to group the initialization, increment and test of the loop variable in a single place:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a;

    printf("Value of a:");
    if (scanf("%d", &a) == 1) {
        int c = 1;
        for (int b = 1; b < a; b++) {
            c = c * b;   // one can also write c *= b;
            printf("%d\n", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```